# Not showing all validation message which are not true in vuetify rules

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vuetify.js

```
<v-text-field
 label='New Password'
 class="required"
 v-model='password'
 type='password'
 :rules="passwordRules"
 required>
</v-text-field>



passwordRules: [
 value => !!value || 'Please enter a password',
 (value) => (value && /\d/.test(value)) || 'Password must include at least one digit',
 (value) => (value && /[A-Z]{1}/.test(value)) || 'Password must include at least one capital letter',
 (value) => (value && /[^A-Za-z0-9]/.test(value)) || 'Password must include at least one special character',
 (value) => (value && value.length > 8 ) || 'Password must be minimum 8 characters',
]
```

I have set the passwordRules for password field. The issue I am facing here is lets say I have entered the special character conditions but at least one digit, capital letter and minimum character conditions are not met still it just shows the *Password must include at least one digit* message rather than all the missing conditions.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Adding error-count="5" resolved my issue

```
<v-text-field
 label='New Password'
 class="required"
 v-model='password'
 type='password'
 :rules="passwordRules"
 error-count="5"
 required>
</v-text-field>
```